# Calculate number of days between specific date and today r

Tags: r

Data:

```
 DB <- data.frame(orderID  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),     
   orderDate = c("1.1.14","16.3.14","11.5.14","21.6.14","29.7.14", 
        "2.8.14","21.9.14","4.10.14","30.11.14","2.1.15"),  
   itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),  
   price = c(29.90, 39.90, 29.90, 19.90, 49.90, 9.90, 29.90, 39.90, 
              14.90, 19.90),
   customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
   dateofbirth = c("12.1.67","14.10.82","6.8.87","12.1.67","12.1.67",
           "6.8.87","14.10.82","14.10.82","12.1.67","12.1.67")
```

Expected outcome [Hope I counted the number of days right]:

```
1.daystilllastorder(here 18.02.2015) = c("47", "137", "200", "47",
"47", "200", "137", "137", "47", "47")
2.daysbetweenthelastorders = c("33", "13","83","33", "33", "83", "13", "13", "33", "33",)
```

Hi guys,

unfortunately I have 3 new problems I´m not able to solve alone - so I would be very pleased if you peeps help me again :) In the data set every order got its own id and every registered user has his unique customerID. Every customer can order items (with ItemIDs), which got specific prices. User has his/her date of birth written in the data bank(as you can see above :D ) I want 
1. Count the number of days from last order (of every customer) till today.
2. Count the number of days between the actual(newest) and the 2. newest order
3. Round the number of days between the orders in total

4. The number of orders during the last full year (Not from today(23.02.2015)-the full year:here 1.1.2014-31.12.2014) When system Date is switching to 2016, it should show me the number of orders in 2015 and so on:hope it´s understandable...

Tried it already like this, but it´s not working:

```
setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")] 
DB[, daystilllastorder := sum(seq[max(orderDate),Sys.Date(),  by = customerID]
DB$orderDate <- as.factor(DB$orderDate)
```

Hope your able to show me what´s wrong or show me another posibility to solve the prob....

Cheers and THX!

Comment: Your second question is unclear. The first one could be solved as follows `setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, "%d.%m.%y")]; DB[, daystilllastorder := Sys.Date() - max(orderDate),  by = customerID]`

Comment: Hi David - nice to hear from you again :) The "13" for user  (in the 2.question) comes from the number of days between the newest order  (on the 2nd january 2015) and the second newest order ( 30th november 2014) - but now I see I made an mistake for that : for user 1 it´s 33 instead of 13 and the second user it´s 13 instead of 33: can you understand now what I mean? I corrected it above

Comment: What is the third question? It's also unclear

Comment: you understand it right!

Comment: You can't just rewrite the whole question from scratch. Not to mention you already asked that exact question. I rolled back to your previous version when the question was still related to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (I don't know if I understood the 3 point correctly, but it seems like you want the average difference between orders?)

First we will convert `orderDate` to an actuall date class, then everything is straight forward

```
setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, "%d.%m.%y")]

DB[,  `:=`(
           daystillastord = Sys.Date() - max(orderDate),
           daysbetlastord = if(.N == 1L) "first order" else as.character(max(orderDate) - max(orderDate[orderDate != max(orderDate)])),
           meandiff = mean(diff(orderDate)),
           OrdsLastFullYear = sum(year(orderDate) == year(Sys.Date()) - 1)
           ),
   by = customerID][]

#     orderID  orderDate itemID price customerID dateofbirth daystillastord daysbetlastord meandiff OrdsLastFullYear
#  1:       1 2014-01-01      2  29.9          1     12.1.67        52 days             33     91.5                4
#  2:       2 2014-03-16      3  39.9          2    14.10.82       142 days             13    101.0                3
#  3:       3 2014-05-11      2  29.9          3      6.8.87       205 days             83     83.0                2
#  4:       4 2014-06-21      5  19.9          1     12.1.67        52 days             33     91.5                4
#  5:       5 2014-07-29     12  49.9          1     12.1.67        52 days             33     91.5                4
#  6:       6 2014-08-02      4   9.9          3      6.8.87       205 days             83     83.0                2
#  7:       7 2014-09-21      2  29.9          2    14.10.82       142 days             13    101.0                3
#  8:       8 2014-10-04      3  39.9          2    14.10.82       142 days             13    101.0                3
#  9:       9 2014-11-30      1  14.9          1     12.1.67        52 days             33     91.5                4
# 10:      10 2015-01-02      5  19.9          1     12.1.67        52 days             33     91.5                4
```

Comment: Thanks david- nearly done:but instead of an "inf" when there´s only one order till now, I want a comment like "first order":how can I do it?

Comment: Which column you referring to?

Comment: the 2. question (daysbetlastorder) Your answering so fast, I was not even able to ad the last question :)

Comment: I added a fourth question-maybe you can also help me? :)

Comment: See my edit. I've modified `daysbetlastorder` and added another column per question 4.

Comment: Hi, the second question is not working, when there are more than one ordered product per day per customer. It´s only correctly working, when one customer orders 1 item-not more then one. Do you have an idea to fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide a data set when its not working?

Comment: Sorry, I can´t it´s to big: I mean "daysbetlastorder"- the number of days is shown correctly, when there is more then 1 order (in total) BUT when there is only one order, with more then one article ordered on the same day (only one order, because all articles ordered on the same day are only one order) it still shows me "inf" - can you understand what I mean?

Comment: Can you help me again David? Seems like you´re quiete genious in R :)

Comment: I would love to help you, but you need to provide a small reproducible example when my code isn't working and what will be your desired output. Otherwise i can't help you.

Comment: Your first answer (before the edit.) was working-the only thing missing was the "first order" comment

Comment: Maybe try to change to `if(length(unique(itemID)) == 1L)` instead of `if(.N == 1L)`

Comment: same result-other ideas?

Comment: The warnings are like:   "1: In max.default(structure(numeric(0), class = "Date"),  ... :no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"

Comment: Can you provide the data you provide in a picture as an actual data? Please also add the desired output for `daysbetlastorder`

Comment: Hey David:good to hear from you buddy! The desired output is written in the question:`daysbetlastorder  = 2.daysbetweenthelastorders (Count the number of days between the actual(newest) and the 2. newest order)`    The actual data is nearly (there are only some unimportant extra columbs) available in the question.

Comment: Well-I took a second look: and maybe I found whats wrong- in your anser the thing with the itemID looks wrong for me: is it possible that there is the mistake?

Comment: it´s not the first order (for me) when the itemID is ordered the first time- it is the first order, when a user/customer orders the first time in the shop!

Comment: Mr. @ David Arenburg? :)

Comment: Made it- was just if(length(unique(customerID )) == 1L) instead of itemID...thanks mate!